# Create unit test with nested function which makes a GrapQL request using fetch api with Jest and React testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch-api, react-testing-library

I have two javascript functions to create a redirect url on server side in Node js (express).

Below the function which makes the GraphQL request and fetch the data:

```
import GET_DATA from './getData.gql';

const getData = async (targetUrl: string) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: GET_DATA,
      variables: {
        targetUrl,
      },
    }),
  };

  const response = await fetch(process.env.ENDPOINT, options);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Unable to parse json response');
  }

  const result = await response.json();

  if (result.errors?.length) {
    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
  }
  return result.data.page;
};

export default getData;
```

And the function which created the redirect url:

```
import getData from './getData';

const getRedirectUrl = async (requestUrl: string) => {
  if (requestUrl.includes('/foo/')) {
    const { content } = await getData(requestUrl);
    if (content.type === 'MyPage') {
      return `/my-page/?id=${content.id}`;
    }
  }
  return null;
};

export default getRedirectUrl;
```

How do I create unit tests for both functions. I am using Jest and [React testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/).

For getRedirectUrl() I have now:

```
describe('getRedirectUrl', () => {
  const mockUrl = '/foo/path/6486867645846';

  it('should create the redirect url', () => {
    expect(getRedirectUrl(mockUrl)).toBe(
      'my-path/?id=e523f6f6-6e73-4bb0-8737-95b63e1f9e6c'
    );
  });
});
```

When I run this test it gives this error:

> ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Af course also I have to somehow mock the GraphQL data which is coming from `getData()` function. How to put this all together?

This function has a nested function `getData()` which retrieves the data witch `fetch` api. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

for function `getRedirectUrl()`, first of all, you shouldn't call the real things that you import, you need to mocking first, in this case, this function is import `getData` from somewhere and used inside this function, that's mean you need to mocking this one first.

EX.

```
import getData from './getData';

describe('getRedirectUrl', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks()
    })
   it('should return url with content id when result from `getData().type` is `MyPage`', async () => {
       // mocking return value
       getData = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
           content: {
               id: '1234',
               type: "MyPage",
           }
       }))
   })
    const mockUrl = '/foo/path/6486867645846';

   const result = await getRedirectUrl(mockUrl)

    expect(getData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockUrl)
    expect(result).toEqual('/my-page/?id=1234')
})
```